# Python 3.6: can't concat str to bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, python-3.6

I have a problem in reading text files in python 3.6.3.

The code is given below:

```
def read_docs(doc):
    files=glob.glob(doc)


    for var in files:
       with open(var,'r', encoding='utf-8') as c1:
          a1=reader(c1,'ignore').read()
```

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: can't concat str to bytes.

I have seen similar questions but I am not clear about how to deal with it. I am stuck as I could not proceed to the application without reading the text files.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try change file mode to `"rb"` like this `open(var, 'rb', encoding='utf-8')`.
File mode `"rb"` returns bytes.
File mode `"r"` returns string.

Check documentation about this function here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open